# Юбилейный день рождения

Tags: тавтология

Меня давно мучает вопрос: правильно ли с грамматической точки зрения выражение 40/50/60.....летний юбилей? Ведь круглая дата - это и есть юбилей. Не получается ли масло масляное? Я думаю, стоит говорить "поздравить с 50-летием" или "поздравить с юбилеем", а не "поздравить с 50-летним юбилеем". Или я не права?

Comment: Вы неправы уже в том, что масло - масл*ян*ое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, формально вы и правы, но:

ЮБИЛЕЙ, -я; м. [от лат. jubilaeus (annus) - юбилейный (год)]
Годовщина чьей-л. жизни, деятельности, существования кого-, чего-л. (обычно о круглой дате). Отмечать ю. Праздновать ю. **В 2003 году трёхсотлетний ю. Петербурга.** (*Выделено мной. – Niemand*) //
Торжество, празднество по этому случаю. Пригласить на ю. На юбилее было много народу. < Юбилейный, -ая, -ое. Ю-ая дата. Ю-ая выставка. Ю-ая медаль. Ю-ое издание. Ю-ая сессия. Ю-ые торжества.

(Большой толковый словарь Кузнецова)